# When does the uniform metric coincide with the sup metric on $C(X,Y)$

Tags: general-topology

Suppose I have two topological spaces $X,Y$, and define the uniform metric defined on $C(X,Y)$ (continuous maps from $X$ to $Y$) to $p^{-}(f,g) = sup$ ${d^{-}(f(x),g(y))}$ where $d^{-} = min (1, d(x,y))$, and the sup metric to be the normal one.

My question is when are these two metrics equivalent topologically. If $X$ is compact, then it seems like  $p^{-}$ will coincide (not sure entirely why). Any insights appreciated.

Comment: They are the same, since for topologies generated by metrics, you just need to look at small balls. I don't feel like giving details. You should look at the proof that, generally, if you a metric $d(x,y)$ generates the same topology as the metric $\min(1,d(x,y))$. Your problem is very similar.

Comment: @mathworker21 ya I was more or less just looking for this type of answer without details anyway, thanks.

Comment: @mathworker21 although I guess I am wondering does it matter if the functions aren't bounded?

Comment: all you care about is the difference of functions. If the difference of two functions is unbounded, then they won't be in the same neighborhood ball no matter which metric you use, if you look at balls with radius less than $1$. So I don't think it does matter whether the functions are bounded or not.

Comment: You have make a correction: $\sup d^{-}(f(x),f(y))$ has to be replaced by $\sup d^{-}(f(x),g(x))$.

Comment: @PaulFrost edited. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not precise.

(1) You should explicitly mention that $Y$ is a metric space (with metric $d$).

(2) If $C(X,Y)$ contains unbounded functions, then there does not exist a "normal" sup-metric. To assure that all functions are bounded, you need additional requirements, for example that $X$ is compact or that $d$ is a bounded metric. Introducing the metric $d^-$ is a standard "trick" to endow $Y$ with a bounded metric which is equivalent to $d$.

So let us assume that all functions in $C(X,Y)$ are bounded with respect to $d$. Only in that case $p(f,g) = \sup_{x \in X} d(f(x),g(x))$ is well-defined. We shall show that $ p^-,p$ induce the same topology. To do this, it suffices to show $p^-(f,g) = p(f,g)$ if $p^-(f,g) < 1$ or $p(f,g) < 1$. This means that $p^-$ and $p$ have the same open $\epsilon$-neighborhoods for $0 < \epsilon < 1$.

Both $p^-(f,g) < 1 $, $p(f,g) < 1$ say that $d(f(x),g(x)) < 1$ for all $x$. Therefore $d^-(f(x),g(x)) = d(f(x),g(x))$ which implies $p^-(f,g) = p(f,g)$.

Edited: It seems to be a good idea to clarify what a "bounded" function is. This is clear if we consider $Y = \mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric $d(x,y) = \lvert x - y \rvert$. In the general case we say that $f$ is bounded if $\delta(f) = \sup_{x,y \in X} d(f(x),f(y)) < \infty$ (that is, if the image $f(X)$ is a bounded subset of $Y$).

a) $p(f,g)$ is well-defined for all bounded functions $f,g$:

Choose any $z \in X$. Then 
$$d(f(x),g(x)) \le d(f(x),f(z)) + d(f(z),g(z)) +  d(g(z),g(x)) \\ \le \delta(f) + d(f(z),g(z)) + \delta(g) .$$

b) If $f$ is undounded and $g$ is bounded, then $\sup_{x \in X} d(f(x),g(x)) = \infty$:

There exist $x_n,y_n \in X$ such that the sequence $(d(f(x_n),f(y_n)))$ is unbounded. Since
$$d(f(x_n),f(y_n)) \le d(f(x_n),g(x_n)) + d(g(x_n),g(y_n)) + d(g(y_n),f(y_n)) \\
\le d(f(x_n),g(x_n)) + \delta(g) + d(g(y_n),f(y_n)) ,$$ at least one of the sequences $(d(f(x_n),g(x_n)))$, $(d(g(y_n),f(y_n)))$ must be unbounded. This implies $\sup_{x \in X} d(f(x),g(x)) = \infty$.

Let us conclude with the remark that bounded metrics $d_1,d_2$ on $Y$ may induce different toplogies on $C(X,Y)$ even if they are equivalent. As an example take $Y = \mathbb{R}$ and$d_1(x,y) = \min(1,\lvert x -y \rvert)$ and $d_2(x,y) = \big\lvert \frac{x}{1+\lvert x \rvert} - \frac{y}{1+\lvert y \rvert} \big\rvert$. Details are left as an exercise!

Comment: But what if $p^{-}(f,g) = 1$ ? Thanks for the answer. It is helping a lot so far. Need to study more....

Comment: We have $p^-(f,g) = 1$ if and only $p(f,g) \ge 1$. This means that open $\epsilon$-neigborhoods with $\epsilon > 1$ in general do not agree (in fact, in this case we have always $B^{p^-}_\epsilon (f) = \{ g \mid p^-(f,g) < \epsilon \} = C(X,Y)$). However, this is irrelevant for the induced topologies which are completely determined by open $\epsilon$-neigborhoods with "small" $\epsilon$.